# Differences between equivalent definitions of algebraic spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space, algebraic-stacks

I have trouble understanding the differences between the following two equivalent definitions of algebraic spaces. Let $k$ be a field.

The first one is

> An algebraic space is an '{e}tale sheaf $(Sch/S)^{opp}_{et}\rightarrow Sets$ such that some axioms are satisfied.

The second one is

> An algebraic space is an '{e}tale sheaf $k{\textrm{-alg}}\rightarrow Sets$ such that some axioms are satisfied.

How can we transform the first definition to the second one? Or how can we transform the second definition to the first one? More precisely, why $(Sch/S)^{opp}_{et}$ becomes $k{\textrm{-alg}}$?

Here is the complete definition of the first one:
[image]

And this is the second one ($\textrm{Aff}_{k}$ is the category of $k$-algebras):
[image]

Comment: You probably need to set $S = \operatorname{Spec} k$ to get the same thing, otherwise the first definition is more general, I think. Also the first screenshot references the fppf topology, not the étale topology.

Comment: @red_trumpet: Well! It can be shown that the algebraic space in fppf topology is the same as the algebraic space in \'{e}tale topology.

Comment: If we take $S$ to be $\textrm{Spec}(k)$, then is $(Sch/S)^{opp}$ equivalent to $k{\textrm{-alg}}$?

Comment: No, but it can be shown that sheaves on affine schemes can be uniquely extended to sheaves on all schemes, provided the topology is finer than the Zariski topology.